# Itext support for transform:scale

Tags: css, itext, html-to-pdf

I'm developing an aplication that the user can either print the current page or add the page to some printing list and then print them merged.

To print the current page I'm using the printing functionality of the browser and everything works fine.

To print the user selection I'm using itext, which receives HTML and returns a PDF which is then downloaded.

My problem is if I feed the Itext solution with exactly the same HTML and CSS used in the printing the current page functionality I have different result (The page generated by Itext uses a different scale) and even If I try to force a diferent scale in the body the results is the same. Do you know how can I solve this?

Best regards

Comment: try to use the media print to put the div's font-size to a certain percentage. If your body has a 62.5% default font-size setting, and your div has 130%, then you targeting the body with a font-size will get ignored in the print. It's a long shot, but you can try this.